# Getting error when applying Smbinning in R

Tags: r

I am working on an example from http://r-statistics.co/Logistic-Regression-With-R.html. I have problem with smbinning code. I am trying to get Information Value via using smbinning.

```
library(smbinning)
# segregate continuous and factor variables
factor_vars <- c ("WORKCLASS", "EDUCATION", "MARITALSTATUS", "OCCUPATION", "RELATIONSHIP", "RACE", "SEX", "NATIVECOUNTRY")
continuous_vars <- c("AGE", "FNLWGT","EDUCATIONNUM", "HOURSPERWEEK", "CAPITALGAIN", "CAPITALLOSS")

iv_df <- data.frame(VARS=c(factor_vars, continuous_vars), IV=numeric(14))  # init for IV results

# compute IV for categoricals
for(factor_var in factor_vars){
  smb <- smbinning.factor(trainingData, y="ABOVE50K", x=factor_var)  # WOE table
  if(class(smb) != "character"){ # heck if some error occured
    iv_df[iv_df$VARS == factor_var, "IV"] <- smb$iv
  }
}
```

This is the code given. I cannot understand the reason behind checking class of the smbinning. My general understanding on smbinning is also not that good.

```
for(vars in factor_vars){
 smb <- smbinning.factor(trainingData, y = "ABOVE50K", x = vars )
 iv_df[iv_df$VARS == vars, "IV"] <- smb["iv"]
}
```

When I run this code I am getting some values NA values. So class checking is apparently needed but why?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you make your question reproducible?

Comment: Hello, how can I do that?

Comment: Sorting [tag:r] questions by popularity, you will find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the example to the letter, your problem would be the following:

1. If you do `smb <- smbinning.factor(trainingData, y="ABOVE50K", x="EDUCATION")` and then `smb`, you get

> [1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/smbinning/smbinning.pdf) "Too many categories"

2. `str(trainingData)` shows that:

> $ EDUCATION    : Factor w/ 16 levels...

3. While the [smbinning documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/smbinning/smbinning.pdf) says that

> maxcat - Specifies the maximum number of categories. Default value is 10. Name of x
>   must not have a dot.

4. Therefore your solution is to use: `smb <- smbinning.factor(trainingData, y="ABOVE50K", x=factor_var, maxcat=16)` in the for loop